# How can Python randomly shuffle a list of 100,000 items?

Tags: python, random, shuffle

I'm trying to perform some statistical analysis on long sequences of numbers.  That requires a randomised shuffle of the list.  The tests are sensitive, so fairness and randomness is very important.  The list is 100,000 integers, but I would like to try 1 million.

---

NB.

- Fairness trumps efficiency or speed.
- I have access to /dev/urandom.
- The USA's NIST laboratory does it using C++ within their entropy measurement suite, SP800-90B, EntropyAssessment.  They sort sequences of 1 million bytes. It's @ https://github.com/usnistgov/SP800-90B_EntropyAssessment.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you use NumPy?

Comment: @NilsWerner I can, but won't that be subject to the 2080 limit?

Comment: No, of course not!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily shuffle millions of numbers in NumPy:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.arange(1e6)
%timeit np.random.shuffle(data)
# 32.7 ms ± 2.25 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: I misunderstood what the "Maximal" link was actually telling me. Of course you're right, of course :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using numpy's `shuffle`?

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html

or permutation if you don't want to do this inplace: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.permutation.html